# Getting single value from multiple values in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like this

```
dic={10:(1,4),20:(2,4),30:(3,4)}
```

how to get `1,2,3` as output using `dic.values()` without using `for` loop.

Comment: You haven't specified what determines the order of `1,2,3`: the first element of each value, sorted?  The first element of the values associated with the sorted keys?  Etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> dic={10:(1,4),20:(2,4),30:(3,4)}
>>> [x[0] for x in dic.values()]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> # Or if you want that as a tuple
>>> tuple(x[0] for x in dic.values())
(1, 2, 3)
>>> # Or a string
>>> ",".join([str(x[0]) for x in dic.values()])
'1,2,3'
>>>
```

You should remember though that the order of dictionaries is not guaranteed.  Meaning, the key/value pairs will not always be in the same order the you put them in.

To get disordered results in the order you want, you should look at [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: +1.  But OP didn't ask for string output.  You're just showin' off, @iCodez. ;)

Comment: @ron.rothman - The OP never said what `1,2,3` was.  It looks like he just wants a list of the values...but I covered all of the bases just in case. ;)

Comment: Actually, `'1, 2, 3'` != `'1,2,3'` :P

Comment: I think you should point out that order of items in dictionaries is not guaranteed and assigning `dic={10:(1,4),20:(2,4),30:(3,4)}` does not necessarily mean that list of values will be in the same order, i,e. `dic.values()` -> `[(1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4)]` is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at what dic.values() produces:

```
>>> dic={10:(1,4),20:(2,4),30:(3,4)}
>>> dic.values()
[(1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Obviously you want the first element of each tuple.

You can use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to get that without looping<sup>1</sup>.

```
>>> zip(*dic.values())[0]
(1, 2, 3)
```

As pointed out in comments, an even more efficient solution is:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> next(izip(*dic.itervalues()))
(1, 2, 3)
```

Then you do not have to go all the way though creating several lists just to get the first element.

The order, of course, depends on the order of the keys in dic.

<sup>1</sup> The 'without looping' is a silly distinction IMHO. Every solution either has an explicit or implicit loop in it...

Comment: I think `itertools.izip` would be better, as it won't create unnecessary list in memory. `next(itertools.izip(*dic.itervalues()))`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Agreed. Edited.

Comment: I agree with your footnote.  I think what the OP meant to say was "in one line", not "without a for loop", because otherwise you are right, looping is inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: You can't. You'll have to loop through the dictionary:

```
for v in d.values():
    print v[0]
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
[v[0] for v in d.values()]
```

This filtering methods are the best you can find :)

Comment: "You can't" directly contradicts your second answer [which proves that you can indeed].

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary whoops, fixed. I meant `values`.

Comment: @ron.rothman But that still counts as looping through the dictionary, doesn't it?

Comment: @aIKid Maybe, maybe not--but OP asks for a solution without a `for` loop, not without *any* loop.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not any better than using iterators, but it has a different approach and maybe it is more suitable for complex tasks:

```
from operator import itemgetter
dic={10:(1,4),20:(2,4),30:(3,4)}
print map(itemgetter(0), dic.values())
```

gives:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using map here.

```
map(lambda x: x[0], dic.values())
```

Comment: Faster than looping. How? `map` with lambda is always slower than the equivalent list comprehension.

Comment: @aro Did you time it?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  Yes, I was always under the impression that map are optimized than looping (mostly because maps are implemented in C). So you mean to say that maps are slower?

Comment: @aro Yes, `map` is slower with `lambda`. But when used with built-in functions it is *slightly* faster than LC.

Comment: @aro You can use 'operator.itemgetter' to avoid using lambda functions (see my answer)